# erase an element in vector by the iterator invalid, but it DOESN'T crash

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    for(vector<int>::const_iterator iter=v.begin();iter!=v.end();iter++) {
        if(*iter==5)
            v.erase(iter);
    }

    for(vector<int>::const_iterator iter=v.begin();iter!=v.end();iter++)
        cout<<*iter<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure the iter is .It should be like the following, or it will crash.

```
for(vector<int>::const_iterator iter=v.begin();iter!=v.end();) {
    if(*iter==5)
       iter=v.erase(iter);
    else
        iter++;
}
```

However, when I run the first program, it outputs:0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9. I read the C++ primer again and again,and googled it, felt confused still.

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn’t have to produce a crash. It could do anything, including appear to work. That’s what makes C++ so much fun!

Answer (score 3):

From [erase](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Basically, it means, that the first code snippet is Undefined Behaviour.

And, as it is Undefined Behaviour, **anything might happen** (a crash is not required, the program might behave as you expected up to some moment in the future when it will suddenly crash).

Comment: Or the true evil: The program appears to run happily and provides results that are off by some amount that is hard to notice until that teeny tiny difference causes a *plane* to crash.